# Liferay - Theme - Questions about get configurable settings via themeDisplay.getTheme().getSetting() in spring mvc controller

Tags: liferay, portal, liferay-theme

This is my question:

I use the following way to add configurable settings to my theme.

`<setting key="theme-mode" configurable="true" value="default"></setting>`

and then use `theme.getSetting("theme-mode")` in my freemarker theme to get the value ,it is working well.

Now I want to get the configurable value in my spring mvc controller:

`ThemeDisplay themeDisplay=(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
String themeMode = themeDisplay.getTheme().getSetting("theme-mode");`

but `themeMode` got `default` ,I already change it in the edit page ,and `theme.getSetting("theme-mode")` in theme is work well.

do you know why ,please tell me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
System.out.println(td.getThemeSetting("theme-mode"));
```

I've tried this on my portlet and it's working